# How to delete a Twitter saved search that has no real-time results

Tags: twitter

I saved a search for **project75**. Since there is no new information (nor will ever be) for this search, I am not able to find the remove option. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a [known twitter bug](http://support.twitter.com/articles/199930-unable-to-remove-saved-searches-known-issue) if you've saved a search that no longer returns any results - the "Remove" link only seems to appear for searches which have results.

This bug was [filed with the API team](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=1779), but they confirmed that it seems to only affect the web interface, and works fine on the api.

Your options are:

1. Fire an [API call](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/saved_searches/destroy/:id) to delete the search. You'll need the search id for this - you can get this by mousing over the search in the sidebar and looking for the id in the url, should look something like `https://twitter.com/search?category=saved_search&id=ID_NUMBER_HERE&q=SEARCH_TITLE&source=sidebar`
2. Simpler way may be to send a tweet with the saved term in it, wait for it to show up in the search results, then delete both the search and the tweet. Not a pretty work-around, but it works!

Comment: Yip totally did not think about the api call. Did the following in curl  `curl -u username:password -X DELETE  https://api.twitter.com/1/saved_searches/destroy/[ID].xml` Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get rid of my own searches because of the same bug, so I made a simple web app to address this: http://www.deletesavedsearches.com/

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the link in the sidebar to show the saved search in the main area, the link that used to say "Save this search" now says "Remove this saved search"

Comment: For me I only get "No real-time results for project75 Search for users » "

Comment: oops, mine did have results